# Averaged first-order difference of Vout in QUCS

Tags: rms, equation, qucs

I am looking at a very simple LM317 voltage regulator circuit to drive a motor (represented by R3 in the diagram). I want to be able to sweep capacitor C2's capacitance and plot the mean 1st-order difference of Vout over time.

I can't seem to define the equation correctly, nor can I add another simulation than the one I already have. For example:

y = rms(diff(Vout.Vt, t))

Just tells me that Vout is undefined and so is t.

I am very new to QUCS, so I apologize if this question is super basic. I've read through the docs but there doesn't seem to be a tutorial for this kind of thing.

Could anyone help me here?

[image: QUCS Picture]

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great answer, but I'm not sure QUCS can do this. I've had a pretty good go, and this is as far as I've got[image: picture of my simulation]

Getting the capacitor sweep is fine, and plotting it over time works. I noticed in your question you asked about sweeping the capacitor, but your image showed R2 set up to be swept so I changed this. I haven't got the label Vout in this image, but I found no problems in using that. I would note

> y = rms(diff(Vout.Vt, t))
>
> Just tells me that Vout is undefined and so is t.

Vout.Vt should work fine, but t should be replaced with "time". QUCS is case-sensitive, and "undefined" means I can't find that variable.

On to the main challenge of plotting the Stddev of the voltage values for different capacitor values, over time.
 QUCS creates its vectors with dependencies. So time is an independent vector of size [steps]. Pr2.Vt is dependent on time, and Cval, so its size is [Cval, time]. What we need to create to get the graph is a vector stddevs of size [time]
using y=stddev(Pr2.Vt) gets a value for all the datasets, whereas we want to do this on a per time step basis.
Starting with our matrix of voltages, which is [time step, cap steps], we can get our values by
stddev(Pr2.Vt[:,0]) - breaking that down

stddev -- function
Pr2.Vt -- Pr2, the name of the probe, Vt voltages array
[:,0] --  all the elements in the first column, ie all the voltage values, for the different capacitor values, at the first time point
If we then repeat 
stddev(Pr2.Vt[:,1])
...
stddev(Pr2.Vt[:,time]
then we could get all the values, but that would be super tedious as there's 100 steps (in my sim). Even then, you'd think that you could create a vector from these values using z = val1, val2, ... valn 
but this doesn't seem to work. If there was a scripting option, or similar it would be doable, but I can't find one. I can't even find how to create these vectors, other than some basic creation tools, and then I can't find how to modify them after thier creation.

As far as I can see, there's no sensible way to do what you need in QUCS natively. If it was something you really needed, I'd suggest writing a script to handle it. QUCS creates a .dat file that outputs the data in a text format, so using something like python to either directly process it, or convert to something like a .csv for use with another software should be simple enough.